# Random assigning different pages in UIpageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to build a app based on information displaying via pageviewcontroller. 
To prevent boredom, i would like to display the pages randomly. Everytime open up the app at different page. How can i do that, below is the code i am using. Thanks

```
_pageTitles = @[@"Over 200 Tips and Tricks", @"Discover Hidden Features", @"Bookmark Favorite Tip", @"Free Regular Update"];
    _pageImages = @[@"page1.png", @"page2.png", @"page3.png", @"page4.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate your datasources, _pageTitles and _pageImages, at startup new with a random number so that the entries each run have another array index. you could do that in viewDidLoad.